# C++ Piping string to mail command

Tags: c++, email, pipe

I am trying to make a c++ program that sends an email using the mail command, using a string as the body. To set the string of the message, I am trying to pipe a message in.

For example, I am trying the following, which should send an email to email@gmail.com with a message saying "test", but no message is sent. Any ideas?:

```
fp = fopen("mail email@gmail.com", "w+");
dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
fclose(fp);
printf("test\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first argument to `fopen` is not a file, and fopen is for opening files.

Try using [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to open a *pipe connected to a subprocess* instead:

```
fp = popen("mail email@gmail.com", "w")
```

Comment: Perfect! fopen was indeed creating a file in the directory entitled "mail email@gmail.com". popen solved the problem.